# how to sort and limit firebase realtime db v9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

devs.
I am trying to make a table that will show the top scorers.
I am new to firebase v9.

problem:
I am using realtime DB for storing the name and scores of users with doc names and names are same.
as I used orderbyValue, orderbykey and orderbyChild. snapshot.val() returns an object which contains objects ( check at the bottom ) which is unordered and don't know how to access all or loop.
for limiting, I tried limitToLast which works fine but sorting doesn't.

help me to sort and limit this.

this is how my data is stored in realtime database

[image: this is how my data is stored]

this is my code to fetch and try to sort

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue, query, orderByChild, limitToLast, equalTo, orderByValue, orderByKey } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-database.js";
var namelist = $('.person');
var list = $('.scores');
// const scoreBoardRef = ref(db, 'users');
const scoreBoardRef = query(ref(db, 'users'), orderByChild('score'));
onValue(scoreBoardRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data); // this returns object containing object and **i don't know how to deal with this.**
    //console.log(scoreBoardRef);
    list[0].textContent = data.score; // here i want score
    namelist[0].textContent = "";//here i want name
//my main goal is to loop through top 3 or 10 data and print it to table

});
```

In the console, this is what I get

```
⬇{abcd: {…}, man2: {…}, nacho: {…}, two: {…}}
 ▶abcd: {name: 'abcd', score: 15}
 ▶man2: {name: 'man2', score: 20}
 ▶nacho: {name: 'nacho', score: 21}
 ▶two: {name: 'two', score: 18}
 ▶[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: It's actually ordered but when you log the browser orders all keys lexicographically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dharmaraj commented: the results in the snapshot are actually ordered, but when you call `snapshot.val()` it gets converted to a JSON object and the keys in a JSON object are by definition not ordered.

To get the results in order, loop over them with `snapshot.forEach`:

```
onValue(scoreBoardRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    const data = child.val();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I did the same you mentioned but it still not giving me sorted results.
https://ibb.co/XDGZpSB
also, the warning on the console says this will sort on the client-side which means that filtering won't reduce the read counts.
how can I resolve these problems?

Comment: Those scores look sorted to me 15 < 20 < 21. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
---
Did you search for that warning message yet? Because that should pretty quickly explain why you get that warning, and [how to fix it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Comment: no, actually it's not it just print the data in the order it is stored in the Rdb.
look what happens if I remove the limit - https://ibb.co/3dXLVdc

Comment: That's unusual (and not showing in the first screenshot).  Can you post an update to your question showing how you implemented the code from my answer?

Comment: **I updated the question.** it's not showing in the first screenshot coz I was using  `limitToFirst(3)`. here ->
```const scoreBoardRef = query(ref(db, 'users'), orderByChild('scores'), limitToFirst(3));```

Comment: It looks like you are querying or printing a snapshot with multiple users/scores in there, which then leads to them being of an undefined order in there. If you query on the right level and loop as shown in my answer, the scores are ordered. For a working example of the code in my answer on your data, see https://jsbin.com/gehepox/edit?html,console. If you're still having a hard time making it work, please provide a similar link that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you Frank my problem is now solved with your help. now only limiting the results left.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what was the final problem that my jsbin MCVE helped you find?

Comment: We missed a little mistake. my mistake was a typo. I was using **scores** instead of **score** because of my older dataset.but `snapshot.forEach` helped. I should edit the question for making it helpful for others.